Understanding binornd() function
When I see the codes of the function that generates random binomial numbers, I am confused by the sentence of this
for i = 1:numel(r(:))
    r(i) = nnz(x(:,i) <= p);
end

is this r(i) = nnz(x(:,i) <= p) equivalent to
if x(:,i) <= p
   r(i)=1;
end

And since p is a number in (0,1), why can we compare a vector with it and how this is related to the formula in the definition of the binomial distribution?

nnz stands for “number of non-zero values”. It looks in the column x(:,i) and counts how many values are smaller or equal to p. You can always compare an array with any number of dimensions to a scalar. Search online for “implicit singleton expansion”.
